# How to set splashscreen dissappear faster

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I noticed that I dont need the splashscreen plugin to use the splashscreen when building with adobe build. 
I created a default app and it takes automatically the screens from res/screen/android.
Pretty nice.. But HOW can I make it dissappear faster. (after the page loads) because on a default app it stays aout 3 seconds and if I manually remove the files from res/screen/android, so it doesn't have anymore splashscreen to load from, it just shows me a black screen wich lasts about 1 secons and a half. How can I make the splashscreen last 1.5 second? so stah it dissappears when the app is loaded.
I do have  but it seems its not working..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
$(function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);               
});

function onDeviceReady() {
       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    });
```

Comment: I solved it by adding the plugin link in config.xml So, at phonegap build page the plugin showed in plugin page and navigator.splashscreen.hide(); is finally working!